# mysql configuration: access denied error (1045)

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, hyper-v

I’m having an issue with mysql on a Hyper-V VM on which I'm using Ubuntu. Some possibly relevant specs for what I’m working with:

```
PHP 7.2.3-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Psy Shell v0.8.18 (PHP 7.2.3-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 — cli)
```

I’m working on a practice project and very new to coding so I may be missing something completely obvious to a non-novice. When I try:

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get the following error:

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas  
  sword: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schem  
  a = mytestproject and table_name = migrations)                                     

In PDOConnection.php line 50:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas  
  sword: YES)                                                                  

In PDOConnection.php line 46:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas  
  sword: YES)
```

I’ve tried to set up my database.php, .env files as follows:

.env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mytestproject
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PORT=6379

CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
```

database.php file:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mytestproject'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ' '),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Mysql users:

```
mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

On the basis of my search for this error, I saw many solutions indicating the .env file and database.php file need to be configured properly, which I tried. I tried setting the root user permissions, changing localhost to 127.0.0.1, etc. I’ve tried everything I’ve come across suggested on various message boards but am led to believe there may be something special about my setup or something I have yet to check to address this error and move forward with my setup. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you able to connect to the db using the mysql client?

Comment: and are you sure your .env file gets loaded?  env isn't a php function (maybe you're using CakePHP?)

Comment: try `mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;` and `> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` than

Comment: Yes, I'm connecting. Using mysql from the terminal though (mysql -u root -p)

Comment: Re: .env file. How can I check it's loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You showed:

In .env file:

```
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

And in database.php:

```
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'),
```

So where right password is?

Comment: in database.php, should it be blank instead of 'mypassword' or should it be 'password' as in the .env file? The actual password is 'mypassword'.

Comment: @A144 i don’t know how configured your environment, but anyway it must be”mypassword” in both files, if it is the correct password

Comment: It makes sense to have the "mypassword" in both database.php and .env but isn't this insecure? I read that it's ok to have the actual password in the .env file but I noticed that people put "secret" or " " in the database.php file. I tried your suggestion and it did work (thank you!), but I'm wondering if it's insecure.

Comment: @A144 I don’t know which framework you tried to use. So, it is just if you want to publish your code on github, in example, and you want that database.php was there, but without your password - this way you can use dotenv loader, where you specify actual credentials, and than in database.php you can use just `env(‘DB_PASSWORD’, ‘secret’);` that means it at first tries to get password from environment variable DB_PASSWORD, and if can’t find it, than use ‘secret’. So, looking forward you env-file doesn’t work. Did you tried this - https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv